# Liquibase could not start correctly

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jhipster, liquibase

What are the reasons why Liquibase not start correctly?

like this in java

```
2021-04-20 13:29:55.795 ERROR 54700 --- [-service-task-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Liquibase could not start correctly, your database is NOT ready: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
```

Comment: `your database is NOT ready: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed` seems like your database closed the connection

Comment: ok i know but why my data base close connection? @Deltharis

Comment: I hope it won't come as a suprise - you'll need to provide some details for anyone without supernatural abilities to be able to answer that.

Comment: It depends on which dev database you selected when you generated your project with JHipster: unless it's an embedded h2 database, you must start it with docker-compose before starting your app. Please read the docs: https://www.jhipster.tech/docker-compose/#4

Comment: @GaëlMarziou i know and my app i run without any error befour updated

Comment: So you updated what? Do you realize that your question is lacking too many details to get help?

Comment: is it an embedded h2 db? if so, make sure you dont have the program running elsewhere in another terminal for example